# Is the product of two functions also a function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Is the product of two functions also a function?

For example, say we have a function $g(x) = xf(x)$ where $f(x)$ is a function. Is it true that that $g(x)$ must also be a function?

Comment: What's a function?

Comment: What are you defining as a function?

Comment: A function is a relation $f:X \to Y$ such that $\forall x \in X, \exists y \in Y$ such that $f(x) = y$.

Comment: @Puzzled417 $\exists$ should be $\exists!$

Comment: Arbitrary sets do not have a product operation, so the idea of the product of two functions is not well defined

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a relation that is a product of two functions. Because they are both functions, they each have one output per input. Then, we multiply those outputs together to get the answer to our relation. So yes, our relation is also a function.

Answer (score 1):

Given the tags ("algebra-precalculus" as opposed to "set theory"), I will assume you're referring to real functions. For some $x$, we have a unique $f(x)$. It suffices to show $g(x) = x \cdot f(x)$ is unique. This is clear; multiplying two real numbers yields a unique real number(this is not hard to prove).